# How to check if mpz_t number is initialized using GMP?

Tags: c++, gmp, bignum

Using GMP library in c++. I have a function that receives a pointer to a mpz_t number and sets another gmp_z number from that. I need a way to check if *_amount has been initialized before.

```
void f(mpz_t* _amount)
{
    mpz_t amount;
    mpz_init(amount);

    if(!_amount){
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    mpz_set(amount, *_amount);
}
```

How can I check if _amount has been initialized previously?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't. I mean, how do you check that an `int` is initialized for example?

Comment: Why are you passing a pointer to `mpz_t`, by the way? `mpz_t` is a reference type.

Comment: Are you able to use the C++ interface?  https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html  Why are you using the C interface?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @John but I'm making some changes in code where c++ interface is not implemented

Comment: @melpomene great, so I think I just can pass mpz_t isn't it? When I try to return an mpz_t, the compiler says function can't return an array

Comment: Indeed, `mpz_t` is an array type. But array parameters decay to pointers.

Comment: Sure. You can pass mpz_t as argument but the library is not designed to return values. Instead, values need to be stored on output arguments. Doc: https://gmplib.org/manual/Parameter-Conventions.html

Comment: It's impossible to check if a POD type has been initialised.

Comment: If you insist on C++, you need to use *proper* classes defined in `<gmpxx.h>` - particularly the `mpz_class`, rather than `mpz_t` which is a C struct with no initialization / scope management whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bad practice in C - end of story. You *don't* check that `_amount` has been initialized. The GMP library is highly optimized, and ensuring an `mpz_t` object is correctly initialized is the only correct approach. So an `mpz_t` object might *look* initialized, but unless `mpz_init(_amount)` has been used, the fields might be uninitialized garbage.

It doesn't matter if `_amount` has already been set. Look at `mpz/set.c` :

```
void
mpz_set (mpz_ptr w, mpz_srcptr u)
{
  mp_ptr wp, up;
  mp_size_t usize, size;

  usize = SIZ(u);
  size = ABS (usize);

  wp = MPZ_REALLOC (w, size);

  up = PTR(u);

  MPN_COPY (wp, up, size);
  SIZ(w) = usize;
}
```

Clearly, if the fields of `mpz_t` (see: `gmp-h.in`) are uninitialized, they *could* be garbage. `mpz_set` could perform `realloc` on contiguous memory that has not been allocated. If you're lucky, that's a crash. If not, the program continues in an undefined state.

It might be useful to think of `mpz_t` as 'C objects'. They are not valid (and cannot be used correctly) until initialized. I would also stress that when it comes to the requirements of GMP (multiple-precision arithmetic), the 'overhead' of initializing a variable (e.g., to zero) is absolutely negligible.

So let's assume `_amount` has been correctly initialized:

---

```
mpz_init(_amount); /* correctly sets mpz_t and assigns (0). */

/* (maybe `_amount` isn't (0)... that's OK too) */

void f (mpz_t *_amount)
{
    mpz_t amount;
    mpz_init(amount);

    /* unless using the GMP C++ interface, there's no definition
     * for the (!) operator. However `mpz_sgn` can be used here: */

    if (mpz_sgn(_amount) == 0) /* (_amount == 0 : exit condition?) */
    {
        mpz_clear(_amount); /* free space occupied by (_amount) */

        /* NOTE: this is NOT C++ with object unwinding! (amount) will
         * potentially leak resources! */

        mpz_clear(amount);
        throw std::bad_alloc {}; /* no leaks; deallocated storage. */
    }

    /* since (amount) will need to be deallocated, and we don't want
     * to deal with assignment errors - we simply 'swap' contents. */

    mpz_swap(_amount, amount); mpz_clear(amount);
}
```

---

I feel you are mixing paradigms here. The use of `throw` in what is essentially C code forces you to manually clean up, and `mpz_t` is *not* a C++ object that 'constructs' to a default, or frees all resources as it destructs / passes out of scope.

You might find the [GMP C++ interface](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html#C_002b_002b-Class-Interface) more appropriate for prototyping your code. `mpz_class` acts as a C++ class, which initializes when instanced, and calls it's destructor at the end of its scope.

Right now you are mixing C/C++ incorrectly, and leaving yourself vulnerable to a lot of bugs, some of which may not cause an immediate crash - and these can be the worst to pin down...

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer @Brett. Why did you use mpz_sgn(amount) as exit condition?  The expected number can be zero.
Anyway, I'm not able to change the code to use c++ interface right now. Which kind of bugs are we leaving with your proposed code?

Answer (score -3):

As _amount is Pointer so you could check for null or void to make sure it is initialize or not.

Thanks

Comment: In fact I'm checking if the pointer _amount is not NULL, but now I'm asking for the content of the pointer.